# Delete group of rows with specific ID conditional on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-delete

I have a table with a couple thousand entries that looks like this:

```
ID    Data Type    Amount
1     Start        
1     Money        13.45
1     Money        3.79
1     Money        46.82
1     END
2     Start
2     Money       26.24
2     END
3     Start
3     END
```

I would like to remove any groups of ID's that look the way that ID=3 looks in the example above where there is only a Start/END but no money. I'm trying to use an inner join to identify these rows but I'm having trouble forming my select statement. How do I select the rows that fit this description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple option:

```
Delete from MyTable
Where ID not in (Select ID from MyTable where [Data Type] = 'Money')
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is called test, the following should do for you.

```
DELETE FROM test 
WHERE id NOT IN (
      SELECT id FROM test WHERE data = 'Money');
```